# Entity Framework 6: Erro no Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou usando o EF6 Code First. Ao realizar o "Update-Database"
o banco é criado normalmente. Mas ao inserir os dados é lançado o seguinte erro:

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.

No Web.config coloquei a connection string com o provider:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StringSqlServerConnection" connectionString="Data Source=NOTE-RAPHAEL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ProjetoTesteDb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Coloquei essa configuração abaixo que vi em um tutorial da Microsoft, mas com isso o programa nem abriu:

```
<configSections> 
    <section name="entityFramework" 
        type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> 
</configSections>
```

Classe de conexão:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext()
        : base("StringSqlServerConnection")
    { }

    ...
}
```

Tenho outros projetos que estão com essa mesma configuração
e não tive nenhum problema.

Comment: coloca sua classe de conexão para ver como ta passando no construtor , ta fazendo em camada separada ?

Comment: Coloquei Eduardo. Sim estou utilizando em camadas separadas com o Repository Pattern.

Comment: @Raphael , qual a necessidade de usar Repository pattern?

Comment: Olá Renan. Seria para deixar isolada a camada de regras de negócio da camada do banco. (Separar as responsabilidades).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso se deve ao fato que, apesar de você estar usando uma referência no projeto, a referência nunca é usada, e o *linker* remove todas as referências que julga não ser usadas no momento da execução do *Seed*.

Essa linha força uma atribuição, e portanto, impede o *linker* de remover a referência por padrão.

Coloque sua classe que herda de  `DBContext` assim:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext()
        : base("StringSqlServerConnection")
    { var chamada = System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance;  }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Valeu Renan, mas o que eu faço com o retorno dessa instância?

Comment: @Raphael , fiz uma edição. faça o teste .

Comment: Obrigado Renan, deu certo! Só achei estranho isso porque você está chamando uma instância e passando ela para uma variável e não está fazendo mais nada hehe.

Comment: @Raphael editei a resposta. Agora com a explicação do que o código faz.

Answer (score 0):

O projeto onde esta mapeado no webconfig a connection string deve estar setado como principal e utilizar  `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient`" ou
fazer com `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["teste"].ConnectionString` as vezes que passei por esse problema resolvi desta maneira

```
   public class Conexao : DbContext
        {
            public Conexao()
                : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["teste"].ConnectionString)
            {

            }     

        }
```

Comment: Suas respostas  estão muito sem formatação.

Comment: Eu fiz dessa mesma forma (ConfigurationManager.Conn...) e deu o mesmo erro. E como que faço para setar a connection string como principal? Talvez pode ser isso.

Comment: botão direito no projeto set As Startup project

Comment: Ah sim, foi a primeira coisa que eu tinha feito hehe.